# Unable to Call Simple Custom Dll Import from C# Application

Tags: c#, c++

**Update**

I have now run through the tutorial 3 times with the same results (Visual Studio/Windows is unable to recognise the DLL as a valid file). This must be an issue with my environment, as mike below ran through the tutorial and it worked fine.

I did notice this in the C++ project's solution explorer on my last run:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is okay? There seems to be a lot of Red stop-signs which to me would suggest something bad...

---

Following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w) tutorial, I have ended up with the following:

**C#**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestImport
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
        public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DisplayHelloFromDLL();
        }
    }
}
```

**C++**

In `.cpp` file `Source Files`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()
    {
        printf("Hello from DLL !\n");
    }
}
```

When debugging in Visual Studio:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in TestImport.exe

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

When running the built EXE (from he same folder as the Dll):

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Have I done anything wrong in the above code? 
I did do all of this in VS 2015, where the tutorial calls for VS 2010, howeve rI couldn't find a more up-to-date tutorial.

---

When I try to add the project as a reference by `Project -> Add Reference ...` I am seeing this error:

```
A reference to 'Path\To\MyLib.dll' could not be added. Please make sure 
that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM
component.
```

Which makes me think that the issue is either with the source code or the DLLs configuration.

I have also tried building both files and putting them in the same folder before running the Executable, but without any improved results (same error as when running the EXE above).

---

Solution Explorer Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Make sure the C++ library's output folder matches where the C# project's output folder is or make a pre-build step that copies to that location (the C++ dll will need to be in the same folder as the C# application).

Comment: Hi crashmstr, thanks for your comment. I have built both projects and put them in the same folder but with the same error. I have also added the dll into the c# debug/release folder but this doesn't help either. Does this seem like the issue is with the dll itself?

Comment: You *can* get that error if some other DLL dependency of the DLL you are using cannot be found, but that would not seem likely here.

Comment: And since it is *not* a .Net DLL or a COM dll, then you cannot add a reference (this is normal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the name of your C++ project and DllImport parameter are the same. Also, if the `dll` file is not located in the same directory as your C# project, make sure to add the `dll` into your `Debug/Release` folder.

Also! Make sure that you are running in the same 32/64 bit mode when compiling.. if you compiled the dll using 32 bit and try to use it in a 64 bit C# program, it won't work.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your answer - do you mean change the name of the Dll to TestImport.Dll before building, or is this what I should change the call to?

Comment: I have tried all of these but with no help - are there any config settings in the dll which I can try changing?

Comment: You have physically copied the `<C++ PROJ NAME>.dll` from the `Debug/Release` folder of the `C++` project and pasted it into the `Debug/Release` folder of your 'C#' project?

Comment: If you have done this, and ensured that `TestLib.dll` is the same exact name as the `.dll` you generated from the `C++` project, this should work.

Comment: Yes I copied the dll into the Debug/Release folder, and the name of the project and final .dll matches that called in the EXE - Perhaps there is a setting I need to change in VS ...

Comment: You shouldn't have to mess with any settings. The error you are getting  is Visual Studio's way of throwing it's hands up in the air because it can't find the file.. there's no other reason you should get that error. Short of taking screenshots of VS projects and the folder contents, I can't offer any other options..

Comment: If you can go to the solution explorer in the C# project, click the `Show All Files` button on the toolbar, expand your` /bin/Debug/` path and take a screenshot of the contents, we might be able to help you.

Comment: It looks like the error now says it can find the file (since moving everything into the same folder), but that the file is of the incorrect format.. I am very new to this so not sure if I am missing anything from the C++ side of things!

Comment: I followed the guide step by step and it works for me.. you might have skipped a step somewhere.

Comment: Okay I added a screenshot I just don't understand this I've done it twice now ... Thanks for your help mike - I guess I will try running through it one more time!

Comment: Thanks for the help mike - I tried following it again to the T but without any luck. I have posted another screen of the C++ project, not sure if that looks normal but that is the only thing I noticed which seemed like it could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about that one.. but check my edit.. go the project properties for the C# one, go to the Build tab, and play with the `Platform Target` combo and see if either the x64 or x86 works

Comment: You sir are a God - I right-clicked my `C++` solution, clicked Properties, and in Configuration Manager changed all the targets to X64, and then did the same with my `C#` app, which was targeting all Platforms, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> OK, now build this application, and then ***copy the previously built DLL into the Debug/Release directory of the current application***. The DLL should be in the same directory as your main application.

Did you do the bolded text?  Your C# app won't know where to look for the DLL and it looks in the build folder, by default.

Comment: Hi Khale, yes I tried this but with no luck! I even added both the completely built EXE and DLL in the same folder but without any improvement!

Answer (score 0):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException'

It happened to me, because of the imported c++ dll, its own dependency dlls were missing.

After copying them into Debug/Release folder everything worked.